# Pandas: Script to fill the gap in IP address number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below

```
 START_IP_NUMBER    END_IP_NUMBER   START_IP_ADDRESS    END_IP_ADDRESS
16777216            16777471                1.0.0.0         1.0.0.255
16777472            16778239                1.0.1.0         1.0.3.255
16802816            16802943                1.0.100.0       1.0.100.127
```

I would like to compare END_IP_NUMBER value ( 16777471) from first row with START_IP_NUMBER value (16777472) form second row and if START_IP_NUMBER(16777472) is stars with after END_IP_NUMBER (16777471)then no action is need and in case if START_IP_NUMBER doesn't starts with after END_IP_NUMBER then consecutive number should be inserted into a row.

example : from the above data frame , new row should be inserted after 2nd row i.e
Start_ip_number = 16778240  and then loop continue if there is any gap need to insert a new row with corresponding Ip numbers.

Please could you help me to suggest.

Comment: Please format the dataframe such that it is readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataframe:
[image]

```
i = 0
while i < len(df)-1:
    i+=1
    line = df.iloc[i:i+1].copy(deep=True)
    curr_START_IP_NUMBER = line.START_IP_NUMBER.values[0]
    curr_END_IP_NUMBER = line.END_IP_NUMBER
    prev_START_IP_NUMBER = df.loc[i-1, 'START_IP_NUMBER']
    prev_END_IP_NUMBER = df.loc[i-1, 'END_IP_NUMBER']
    # if no gap - continue
    if curr_START_IP_NUMBER == (prev_END_IP_NUMBER + 1):
        continue
    # else fill the gap
    # new line start ip number
    line.START_IP_NUMBER = prev_END_IP_NUMBER + 1
    # new line end ip number
    line.END_IP_NUMBER = curr_START_IP_NUMBER - 1
    line.START_IP_ADDRESS = 'not found'
    line.END_IP_ADDRESS = 'not found'
    # insert the line between curr index to previous index
    df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:i], line, df.iloc[i:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result df:
[image]

You didn't talk about how to handle the start/end IP addresses so you can update them as you wish in the line parameters.

Comment: updated the solution with the not found part

Comment: Yes, solution is working fine and tried to convert the IP number to IPv4 address using the below code but getting an error message as below# new line start ip number
    line.START_IP_NUMBER = prev_END_IP_NUMBER + 1
    line.START_IP_ADDRESS= str(ipaddress.IPv4Address("line.START_IP_NUMBER"))
    # new line end ip number
    line.END_IP_NUMBER = curr_START_IP_NUMBER - 1
    line.END_IP_ADDRESS = str(ipaddress.IPv4Address("line.END_IP_NUMBER")) Error is : AddressValueError: Expected 4 octets in 'line.START_IP_NUMBER'  .. Please suggest

Comment: Done.. I will raise a new question